# MapBox doesn't really delete the tileset data

Tags: mapbox

I have a recipe.json file:

```
  "version": 1,
  "layers": {
    "tree_points_layer": {
      "source": "mapbox://tileset-source/my_name/zh-trees",
      "minzoom": 0,
      "maxzoom": 16
    }
  }
}
```

I use tile set command line utilities to upload and publish my data in three steps:

```
$ tilesets upload-source my_name zh-trees small_data.json
$ tilesets create my_name.zh-trees --recipe recipe.json --name "ZH Trees"
$ tilesets publish my_name.zh-trees
```

Then I delete the tileset (80K features in it) from the web UI https://studio.mapbox.com/tilesets/ and then upload another source (with only 7 features in it). When the publishing finishes, I see that the number of markers on the map is still thousands instead of 7.
How am I supposed to get rid of the data completely? Do I have to write a new url each time? Does it not clutter my account?

Answer (score 0):

There is a --replace flag which will replace features, not append. Try this:

```
tilesets upload-source --replace my_name zh-trees small_data.json
```